# Not Underlined link in HTML

Tags: html, css

How to get a link not underlined in HTML?

Answer (score 7):

It can be done in following ways:

1) If you want to remove underline from specific link, then use

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">Some text</a>
```

2) To remove the underline from entire html page, Create a .css file, In that write following:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

It will suppress underline from every anchor tag.

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing at what your next question would be....

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone above said, but I wouldn't use inline styles.

Rather set a class for all links that you do not wish to have underlined.

```
<a href=#" class="nolines">Your link</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.nolines{text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to do that in CSS.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Or, as an inline style:

```
<a href="http://foo.bar/something" style="text-decoration:none">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

for one link, use style="text-decoration:none"

if you want it for the whole site:

```
<style> a { text-decoration:none; } </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS. The property you need to set is `text-decoration: none;`